# Camera Intent return null only on some devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I am using camera to capture image and set the returned bitmap into an imageview but it is crashing on OnePlus devices. I checked on few htc devices and it is working perfectly. I checked for solutions and they said to check for request code but I am already doing it. What can be the problem here?

Here is the code

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
        }
    });
```

and onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == -1) {
        image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Must compress the Image to reduce image size to make upload easy
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        // Encode Image to String
        encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        img_path = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
      //  Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    }
}
```

and the stack trace of error

> STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.madhours/com.madhours.activities.ActivitySignUp}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object
>   reference     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3659)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3702)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:155)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object
>   reference     at
>   com.madhours.activities.ActivitySignUp.getRealPathFromURI(ActivitySignUp.java:134)
>     at
>   com.madhours.activities.ActivitySignUp.onActivityResult(ActivitySignUp.java:116)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6218)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3655)
>     ... 10 more java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object
>   reference     at
>   com.madhours.activities.ActivitySignUp.getRealPathFromURI(ActivitySignUp.java:134)
>     at
>   com.madhours.activities.ActivitySignUp.onActivityResult(ActivitySignUp.java:116)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6218)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3655)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3702)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:155)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Answer (score 1):

> What can be the problem here?

The problem is that you are calling `getData()` on the returned `Intent`. Returning a `Uri` is not part of [the `ACTION_MEDIA_STORE` contract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Given that you did not put `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `Intent` you used with `startActivityForResult()`, the only result you will get is the `Bitmap` in the `data` extra.

If you want a full-size image written somewhere, provide a path to that location in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then hold onto that path and use it when `onActivityResult()` is called:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2016 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      File dir=
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

      dir.mkdirs();
      output=new File(dir, FILENAME);
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }

    if (output.exists()) {
      output.delete();
    }

    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to set the image into imageview in onActivityResult?

Comment: @VivekMishra: Use your favorite [image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: using Uri.fromFile(output)??because if I use data it is giving null pointer exception

Comment: @VivekMishra: Either the `Uri` or the `File` itself should be fine for most image-loading libraries. If it is `null`, the perhaps you failed to hold onto it in the saved instance state `Bundle`.